# Java UDP data format

Tags: java, udp, format

I need to send a UDP packet in the following format:

[1 OCTET][2 OCTET][3 OCTET][4 OCTET][5 SHORT]

For example:

> 77.125.65.201:27015

Hexadecimal:

> 4D 7D 41 C9 69 87

This is what I captured with wireshark:

[image]

Why is 2 extra OCTET [00, 00] ?

And this is how I format:

```
byte[] responseHeader = { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, 0x66, (byte)0x0A };
byte[] testIP = getByteIp("77.125.65.201:27015");
byte[] response = new byte[responseHeader.length + testIP.length];
System.arraycopy(responseHeader, 0, response, 0, responseHeader.length);
System.arraycopy(testIP, 0, response, responseHeader.length, testIP.length);

private byte[] getByteIp(String fullData){
    String[] data = fullData.split(":");
    byte[] returnArray = new byte[8];

    byte[] ip = new byte[4];
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName(data[0]).getAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] port = new byte[2];
    port = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(Integer.parseInt(data[1])).array();

    System.arraycopy(ip, 0, returnArray, 0, ip.length);
    System.arraycopy(port, 0, returnArray, ip.length, port.length);

    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the port number is a 2 byte value, but you are treating at a 4 byte value.  If you look closely, you will see that you have 8 bytes instead of 6, and the two "significant" bytes appear after those zeros.

Anyway, the following code should do what you are trying to do.

```
byte[] port = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(
        (short) Integer.parseInt(data[1])).array();
```